# Symfony admin generator: To be or not to be?

Tags: symfony1

on the last projects i've started, I wondered if I should use the admin generator or not. My usual choice is to not use it, as some developers suggested to me, "unless it's for quick backend prototyping and submission to client", they said. Currently i'm starting a project and i'm  in the situation that the client need the backend very fast to start loading lots of data, and i'm doubting about using the admin generator or not. I would use it if needed simple form fields. But one of my models must have multiple images, and maybe I need a more complex view that allow the client to load N images, so the admin generator maybe it's not the best choice, but it seems fast, it seems to save time and that's what I need now, time saving!
The project is very simple, it's just a Product model with multiple images and multiple sizes and belongs to a simple category.
What do you think? What would be the best option for this? And where do you think that makes sense to use the admin generator or the regular module generator?
Thanks in advance!
Regards.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I use the admin generator as much as possible.  It is really designed to be great for the "backend" of your website-- the administrative screens which authors and editors will use to maintain the app.  Any module that needs to be user-editable and is simple cries out for the admin generator.

Recently I have been starting everything with the admin generator so that there's a working prototype to build data with.  Then I select certain modules or views that need more magic sauce, and build them out with more customization.

Remember, you can add views and forms to an admin generator module.  On my last project I used the admin generator for the "edit" action of my main object but added "show" methods similar to a non-admin-generator form-- adding an `executeShow()` action and `showSuccess` template.

The other thing to keep in mind is that the admin generator is **only a generator**.  It writes a bunch of code for you in `cache/frontend/env/modules`, but you can override any of it by building the equivalent code in `apps/frontend/modules/`.  If you find one part of it that you can't configure with generator.yml, you can copy the file out of the cache into your module dir and hack away.  I prefer to take the "out of the box" admin generator as far as possible before customizing it, though.

Comment: I'm with Nathan; the admin gen is so powerful and easy. Further it's easy to customize in the back and front ends. The admin gen is the reason I'm still with s1.4 instead of s2, despite the fact that I'm in love with s2's Bundle architecture.

Answer (score 1):

i've been working with symfony for quite some time now and i've been using the admin generator for simply and complex situations. It's true that it saves time when developing CRUD modules, but i dont think that is not advisable for complex cases.

I think you should use it and also learn the power of customization the generator gives you. If you have complex Forms, leave that for form classes to manage and as you said, if your forms a quite more complex to render, well you should only take care of the rendering of that only segment of the view.

But, if you decide to make if without it, you should start thinking about creating all the view from scrap, that in my case takes quite time ( i'm not so versatile wiht css).

But this is only my opinion, hope this helps you make a more rational choice!